# Order By date for multiple date rows

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-aggregation

I am trying to write an sql query to combine a rows so the result will look something like this:

| post_id | date_1 | time_1 | date_2 | time_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 20220303 | 20:00:00 |  |  |
| 500 |  |  | 20220202 | 20:00:00 |

Here is what Ive tried so far:

```
SELECT 
    CASE meta_key WHEN"performance_date_1"THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END  AS date_1,
    CASE meta_key WHEN"performance_date_2"THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END  AS date_2
FROM test;
```

Schema SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  meta_id bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  post_id INT,
  meta_key varchar(255) NULL,
  meta_value longtext NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`)
);
INSERT INTO test (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (500, 'performance_date_1', '20220303');
INSERT INTO test (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (500, 'performance_time_1', '20:00:00');
INSERT INTO test (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (500, 'performance_date_2', '20220202');
INSERT INTO test (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (500, 'performance_time_2', '20:00:00');

INSERT INTO test (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (501, 'performance_date_1', '20220403');
INSERT INTO test (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (501, 'performance_time_1', '20:00:00');
INSERT INTO test (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (501, 'performance_date_2', '20220407');
INSERT INTO test (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (501, 'performance_time_2', '19:00:00');
```

SQL Fiddle
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Zxq4HJpuAiSPvabQzL4ux/1

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can simplify your code to:

```
SELECT post_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', 2) = 'performance_date' THEN meta_value END) new_date_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', 2) = 'performance_time' THEN meta_value END) new_time_1
FROM test
GROUP BY post_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', -1);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb78e7282010710e0257addd3d48ed25).

Comment: Nice thats a lot more simplified and probably better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    post_id,
    MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'performance_date_1' THEN meta_value END) AS date_1,
    MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'performance_time_1' THEN meta_value END) AS time_1,
    MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'performance_date_2' THEN meta_value END) AS date_2,
    MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'performance_time_2' THEN meta_value END) AS time_2
FROM test
GROUP BY
    post_id;
```

Comment: Thats very close. But I am trying to have 2 rows with the same post_id. One will only have the date_1/time_1 and the second row will have date_2/time_2. Similar to the example table I showed above in my question.

Comment: Why do you want this output?

Comment: Later on in PHP I will be looping through all the post_ids to displaying the data. But I guess I can adjust the data to how I want with PHP if this isnt possible in SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim Biegeleisen for putting me on the right track. I ended up using your query
as a sub query and then `UNION ALL` and I achieved the results I needed. The results table looks slightly different then my original question, but it works for me.

Query SQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
  (SELECT
      post_id,
      MAX( CASE meta_key WHEN"performance_date_1"THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END ) AS new_date_1,
      MAX( CASE meta_key WHEN"performance_time_1"THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END ) AS new_time_1
  FROM test
  GROUP BY post_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      post_id,
      MAX( CASE meta_key WHEN"performance_date_2"THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END ) AS new_date_1,
       MAX( CASE meta_key WHEN"performance_time_2"THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END ) AS new_time_1
  FROM test
  GROUP BY post_id) as T1
ORDER BY post_id
```

Results:

| post_id | new_date | new_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 20220303 | 20:00:00 |
| 500 | 20220202 | 20:00:00 |
| 501 | 20220403 | 20:00:00 |
| 501 | 20220407 | 19:00:00 |